# Converting "wet" contact closure to "dry" contact closure

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have a "wet" contact closure circuit that is outputting 3V DC. I need to eliminate that voltage to create a "dry" contact closure.

How is this accomplished ? Please answer in very basic language, as I am not an electronics expert - just a tinkerer.

Answer (score 2):

A dry signal is just a contact closure.

You can use a 3V relay driven by your 3V  signal. If the 3V signal does not have enough current capability to drive a 3V relay directly you will need to add a driver transistor and supply appropriate power for the relay coil. Typically this would involve a transistor, base series resistor, diode across the relay coil and the relay itself.

Answer (score 1):

A 'wet' contact has one side connected to a voltage supply which it switches to the load, while a 'dry' contact is uncommitted (not connected to anything) and can be wired however you like.

To eliminate the voltage supplied to a 'wet' contact you just have to disconnect it. Depending on how the relay circuit is constructed you may need to remove a jumper, unscrew a terminal, snip a wire or cut a pcb trace - whatever it takes to get the 3V off the relay contact terminal that it is connected to.

Once the contact is freed up you can then connect it to the circuit you want to switch (which may require soldering a wire directly onto the contact terminal).